# Help to: Convert a sql command to EF 4.1 Code First

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have this schema:

[image]

...and I want to select some records using this query:

```
SELECT
    Articles.ArticleId,
    Articles.Title, 
    Articles.Tooltip, 
    Articles.UriTitle, 
    Articles.SubTitle, 
    Articles.Published,
    Tags.TagId
FROM Articles INNER JOIN
     ArticleTag ON Articles.ArticleId = ArticleTag.ArticleId INNER JOIN
         Tags ON ArticleTag.TagId = Tags.TagId
WHERE (Tags.TagId = @tagid) AND (Articles.Published = 1)
```

Can anybody help me to convert this query to EF 4.1 Code First (a lambda expression) please?

**UPDATE:**

I use [@Ladislav Mrnka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/413501/ladislav-mrnka) code (as a lambda expression) and code works! Now I put generated sql here, and check it please to ensure there is no problem:

```
// C#:
var query = context.Articles.Where(a => a.Published && a.Tags.Any(t => t.TagId == tagId))
                            .Select(a = new {
                                a.ArticleId,
                                a.Title,
                                a.Tooltip,
                                a.UriTitle,
                                a.SubTitle,
                                a.Published
                            });
```

and the generated sql is

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ArticleId] AS [ArticleId], 
[Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent1].[Tooltip] AS [Tooltip], 
[Extent1].[UriTitle] AS [UriTitle], 
[Extent1].[SubTitle] AS [SubTitle], 
[Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
[Extent1].[Keywords] AS [Keywords], 
[Extent1].[MetaDescription] AS [MetaDescription], 
[Extent1].[CreatedAt] AS [CreatedAt], 
[Extent1].[UpdatedAt] AS [UpdatedAt], 
[Extent1].[Viewed] AS [Viewed], 
[Extent1].[Published] AS [Published], 
[Extent1].[Body] AS [Body]
FROM [dbo].[Articles] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Published] = 1) AND ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[ArticleTag] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[ArticleId] = [Extent2].[ArticleId]) AND ([Extent2].[TagId] = @p__linq__0)
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
int tagId = ...;
var query = from a in context.Articles
            where a.Tags.Any(t => t.TagId == tagId) && a.Published 
            select new 
               {
                   a.ArticleId,
                   a.Title,
                   a.Tooltip,
                   a.UriTitle,
                   a.SubTitle,
                   a.Published,
                   tagId // I'm not sure if this will work but let give it a try  
               };
```

If selecting `TagId` doesn't work it is not too big problem because you know that all records have same tag Id.

Comment: Thanks. I test it just now. (I want use this idea with a lambda expression. ). I'll write result here.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear @Ladislav Mrnka! It works!!! I use idea as a lambda expression and it works. Thanks a mil. I put the generated sql as an update in origin question, and check it if is correct please. Thanks again.